# Date conversion error in SQL on one Computer, but the code works on another?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have this piece of Code

```
Select * FROM [DB].[dbo].[STG_TABLE]
WHERE convert(datetime, cast([CHANGE_DATE] as char(8))) > DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())
```

The CHANGE_DATE is of type numeric(8,0).

I have used this code before. It still works on my local machine on the same data, but when I run this on the Development server, it gives an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Both computers has the same system date settings in the Control panel.

If I remove the convert, like so:

```
Select * FROM [DB].[dbo].[STG_TABLE]
WHERE cast([CHANGE_DATE] as char(8)) > DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())
```

it gives the same error which leads me to believe it is after the greater than, but I still don't know why.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings or numeric values - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: what do these numbers look like? And you still get the error because `datetime` has a higher precedence than `varchar` so you get an implicit conversion if you don't specify an explicit one.

Comment: I understand that, but it is the type it is in on the source, I can't change that sadly.

Comment: The result looks like '20130115' YYYYMMDD

Comment: Leaving aside, for now, that as marc_s says, this is a really poor design, the code *should* work if all of the numbers *are* YYYYMMDD. It makes me suspect that you actually have different data on the two machines and that on the second machine, you've got data that's out of range, e.g. 20130230

Comment: Thank there exists a value in that field that is = '0' which is most probably the culprit. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try another convert.

```
Select * FROM [DB].[dbo].[STG_TABLE]
WHERE [CHANGE_DATE] >  cast(convert(char(8),DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()),112) as numeric(8,0))
```

GetDate() -> CHAR(8) -> NUMERIC and then compare to table field

Comment: I was going to answer with practically the same (except I include the extra hop all the way to `numeric(8,0)`)

Answer (score 1):

Also try to check dates in your table

```
SELECT [CHANGE_DATE]
from [DB].[dbo].[STG_TABLE]
where isdate(cast([CHANGE_DATE] as char(8)))=0
```

Comment: There was a '0' in that field

Comment: Instead of putting a second answer, you could have just edited your first one.